# Email not displaying image properly

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-email

I've created an email format that should include an image of our company logo.  When I first wrote the img tag in sharepoint 2013 designer, I created it like this:

```
<img src="https://pathToImg" alt="Error text" align="right">
```

And this worked.  The image was shown in my email.  However, the image was a little too large, and it started to wrap my text, so I thought about sizing it in the tag.  I then changed my image workflowvariable to show this:

```
<img src="https://pathToImg" height="75" width="200" alt="Error text" align="right">
```

This is what caused the problems.  The image now displays as a broken img, with the error text message.  If I click the broken image, the image then shows correctly.  And after a little bit (maybe like 30 seconds to 1 min), the image will display correctly as well.  Does anyone know what could be causing this?  All I am doing is just resizing the image, as far as I am aware.

Also, it should be noted that I am using Outlook 2013 as my email client.

Comment: Where is the image hosted?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this

```
<img src="https://pathToImg" style="height:75px;width=200px;" alt="Error text" align="right">
```

Comment: Isnt' working unfortunately, it just goes back to the original size before trying to reformat.  While doing this though, I noticed that when I opened the email, for a split second, the image was that broken image thing that I am trying to correct.  Since my original way displayed after a while, is it maybe Outlook that's causing problems?

Comment: Not sure, may be you need to re size the original image and then give the path

Answer (score 0):

You can use the HTML-Style tag in Mails as well.

For example:

```
<img src="url" style="width: 150px;" />
```

Here's more about that tag: [W3Schools style tag](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_styles.asp)

Another way would be to reformat the source image itself to a proper mail-format.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/121108)

Comment: I've changed my answer as suggested.